# I don't have MS Word installed on my system, is there a way to use/include MS Word reference to be included in my VB 6 program?

Tags: ms-word, vb6, ms-office

I don't have MS Word installed on my system, is there a way to use and/or  an  MS Word reference in my VB 6 program?

Comment: Nope.  Word Automation requires Word to be installed. It needs this in order to make use of Word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the use Word automation always requires that Word is installed on the system.

Depending on what you are trying to achieve there are multiple alternatives though:

- OpenXML SDK: For basically anything that does not require the document to be rendered (e.g. conversion to PDF does require rendering), you can directly manipulate the contents of the file using the API provided by the SDK. As the SDK is independent of Word/Office, you can use this approach anywhere you like, be it client-side or on the server, e.g. for server-side document creation and manipulation.
- Word Automation Services: If you are within SharePoint and you need to manipulate or convert documents, then this would be the tool of choice.
- Third-party libraries: For instance, Aspose offers a great library for automating and converting Office documents.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using [late binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/0tcf61s1). You can write code to use Word by dimming an object variable and using `CreateObject` to create a Word Application object, but you can't debug it. Like @Dirk Vollmar says, it depends on what you're trying to do as to whether this makes you life inconvenient, or a nightmare.

Here is a slightly modified version of a code sample from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/177097

```
Sub RunWord()

   Dim wObj as Object    'must use object instead of Word.Application because Word is not installed
   On Error Resume Next

   ' Get existing instance of Word if it exists.
   Set wObj = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

   If Err <> 0 then
      ' If GetObject fails, then use CreateObject instead.
      Set wObj = CreateObject("Word.Application")
   End If

   ' Add a new document.
   wObj.Documents.Add

   ' Exit Word.
   wObj.Quit

   ' Clear object memory.
   Set wObj = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Please note that this code still requires Microsoft Word to be installed on the system.

Comment: @DirkVollmar I understand it requires MS Word to work, but it does not require MS Word in order to develop. If I read the OP correctly, that was the question.

Comment: I was talking about the development phase. But as far as i know, it would work without ms word on a client system